# Cannot start OpenDebug because Mono (or a Mono version >= 3.10.0) is required

Tags: mono, visual-studio-code

I have downloaded and install vscode in ubuntu 14.0 lts, and include existing node.js project. First think I have to do with vscode is debugging my app, for that I have go to debug (ctrl+shift+D) penal, configure launch.json file with "name" and "program"="app.js" properties. Put debug point in app.js file and click on run button. Here I am getting error "Cannot start OpenDebug because Mono (or a Mono version >= 3.10.0) is required". How to solve it?

Comment: Take a look here and see if it answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29991543/1864167

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
mono --version # Mono JIT compiler version 4.0.1 (tarball Tue Apr 28 11:47:58 UTC 2015)
```

Source: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/

Comment: `sudo apt-get -y install mono-devel` was required in my case before installing mono-complete

Answer (score 0):

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/), cross platform, open source .NET framework, needs to be installed in the system. Please visit [Mono - Download](http://www.mono-project.com/download/) section and its corresponding [installation guide](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/) to install.

Once installed you should be able to perform the [debug operations](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/debugging).