# "Cannot start Omnisharp because Mono version >=3.10.0 is required"

Tags: .net, linux, mono, visual-studio-code

I just installed Visual Studio Code and when I started it, it gives me this error. When I try to execute my example application, it gives me `TypeLoadExceptions`.

> Cannot start Omnisharp because Mono version >=3.10.0 is required

Comment: This question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29959239/cant-start-omnisharp-because-of-mono-version (Mac-specific) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985029/cannot-start-opendebug-because-mono-or-a-mono-version-3-10-0-is-required (Different cause).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you installed it, you probably used

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

In my case, this installed Mono 3.2.8 which is evidently lower than 3.10.0. I couldn't manage to upgrade my Mono installation to a more recent version until I found this workaround:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-devel
```

This will install the developer package which, as of yesterday, comes with Mono 4.0.1. This will replace your existing Mono 3.2.8 installation with the newest version and when you restart VS Code, you'll notice that the error is gone and everything seems to work perfectly. Likewise, executing a program will also no longer have `TypeLoadExceptions`.

I blogged about this in more detail [here](http://www.vannevel.net/2015/05/01/hello-linux/).

Comment: You can use `mono -V` to determine which version of mono you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

I still can't update my mono version using `sudo apt-get install mono-devel` until I follow the [official website](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives).

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: And then `apt-get install mono-complete` (or `apt-get upgrade` if you already have mono) should suffice, rather than needing `mono-devel`.